# pymodbus writing multiple register float format

Tags: pymodbus

I'm reading from an object the correct registers value

```
from pymodbus.payload import BinaryPayloadDecoder
from pymodbus.payload import BinaryPayloadBuilder
from pymodbus.client.sync import ModbusSerialClient as ModbusClient

class modbusRW(object):
    def init(self):
        self.client = ModbusClient( 
            method=self.method,
            port=self.port,
            parity='N',
            stopbits=self.stopbits,
            bytesize=self.bytesize,
            baudrate=self.baudrate,
            timeout=self.timeout)


    def read(self):           
        modbus_address = 41023
        modbus_count = 10
        modbus_unit = 1
        e = 0
        time.sleep(constant.modbus_connection_delay)
        self.connect()
        result = self.client.read_holding_registers(
              modbus_address,
              count=modbus_count,
              unit=modbus_unit)
        decoder = BinaryPayloadDecoder.fromRegisters(
                result.registers, wordorder=Endian.Little, byteorder = Endian.Big)
            
        self.close()
        e = { 'Counter 1':  decoder.decode_32bit_float(),
              'Counter 2':  decoder.decode_32bit_float(),
              'Counter 3':  decoder.decode_32bit_float(),
              'Counter 4':  decoder.decode_32bit_float(),
              'Counter 5':  decoder.decode_32bit_float()}
```

now I'm trying to write a value (0.0) on the same address (only counter 1)

```
def write(self):
    modbus_address_reset = 41023
    modbus_count = 2
    modbus_unit = 1
    modbus_reset_value = 0.0

          
    builder_reset = BinaryPayloadBuilder(wordorder=Endian.Little, byteorder = Endian.Big)
    builder_reset.add_32bit_float(modbus_reset_value)
    payload_reset = builder_reset.build()           
            
    time.sleep(constant.modbus_connection_delay)
    self.connect()
            
    result_reset = self.client.write_registers(
                address= modbus_address_reset,
                values= payload_reset,
                count = modbus_count,
                unit = modbus_unit)
            
    self.close()
```

but the code goes to error...

```
 **required argument is not an integer**
```

what wrote I wrong?

thank for your help

I'm expecting to write the same holding register. On the code I wrote only the highlights of the object class

To test, I got the same error also if I try to execute the code below (write a single register)

```
result_reset = self.client.write_register(41023, 0, unit=1)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I add skip_encode = True like parameter on write registers function, everything working fine

```
result_reset = self.client.write_registers(
            address= modbus_address_reset,
            values = payload_reset,
            count = modbus_count,
            unit = modbus_unit,
            skip_encode = True)
```